# Nginx high resource usage when applying wordpress nginx config

Tags: nginx, web-server, wordpress, web

I have a website `www.mywebsite.com` and I installed a wordpress site in a sub directory `www.mywebsite.com/newrs/`

The wordpress site loads fine but I need to add some config in the nginx to make the wordpress pretty url's work like:

```
www.mywebsite.com/newrs/view-candidates/
```

So what I did is I added a config file. It looks like:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    root /home/mysite/www.mysite.com/html;
    expires 365d;
}

location / {
    #rewrite ^/([^.?]*)(/?)$        /index.php?url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]*)$      /index.php?url=$1 last;
    root /home/mysite/www.mysite.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location /newrs {
    rewrite ^/([^/]*)$      /index.php?url=$1 last;
    root /home/mysite/www.mysite.com/html/newrs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /newrs/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

So I just added this code block:

```
 location /newrs {
    rewrite ^/([^/]*)$      /index.php?url=$1 last;
    root /home/mysite/www.mysite.com/html/newrs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /newrs/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
 }
```

So In saved it and restart nginx. Browsed /newrs and the pretty url's now working fine but the loading time is so slow, and when i checked the server resource load, my CPU usage almost go as high as 96%.

So I removed the `location /newrs` code block in the nginx config file and the server resource load is back to normal but of course, wordpress pretty url's would not work agai.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Something isn't quite right, because Nginx is exceptionally lightweight. Compared with PHP and MySQL it uses approximately zero CPU, even when it's caching. I guess there's some kind of looping or forwarding going on, but I can't spot what. What's in your access / error logs that looks relevant? I use Wordpress to create nice URLs, not Nginx.

Comment: @Tim I'll try to check any access error. Yep I also use wordpress to create url's problem is, I guess it needs some config to take effect if you are using nginx.

Comment: You can download my Nginx configuration files for Wordpress on page1 of my [Nginx / Wordpress tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/).

Comment: Which process was using the CPU?